# Ajax heavy JS apps using excessive amounts of memory over time

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, memory-leaks

I seem to have some pretty large memory leaks in an app that I am working on. The app itself is not very complex. Every 15 seconds, the page requests approx 40kb of JSON from the server, and draws a table on the page using it. It is cheaper to draw the table over because the data is usually always new. I am attaching a few events to the table, approx 5 per line, 30 lines in the table. I used jQuery's .html() method to put the new html into the container and overwrite the existing. I do this specifically so that jQuery's special cleanup functions go in and attempt to detach all events on the elements in the element that it is overwriting. I then also delete the large variables of html once they are sent to the DOM using `delete my_var`.

I have checked for circular references and attached events that are never cleared a few times, but never REALLY dug into it. I was wondering if someone could give me a few pointers on how to optimize a very heavy app like this. I just picked up "High Performance Javascript" by Nicholas Zakas, but didn't have much time to get into it yet.

To give an idea on how much memory this is using, after 4~ hours, it is using about 420,000k on chrome, and much more on Firefox or IE.

Thanks!

Comment: To get a helpful answer, you will probably need to provide a code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Would have to see code to be more helpful. If it happens in FF *the chances are it's due to non-released resources or execution contexts*. Older versions of IE were (more) susceptible to the "object lifetime mismatch" between DOM and JS engine. Remember, even if you reset the data in an execution context, you haven't killed the execution context! (It really is a bug if a browser doesn't release events of elements that are dropped from the DOM.) This bug sounds fun, please update with (minimal) test-case :-)

Comment: I will try to build a simple JS file that shows the same symptoms.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: In order to avoid guessing: **(1)** are you using JSONP or XMLHTTP (default in jQuery)? **(2)** How does the response look like? One big html? Serialized objects which later turned into elements?

Comment: Using the latest stable version of jquery, and I'm using getJSON. The response is a json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest writing a test version of your script without events. DOM / JS circular references might be very hard to spot. By eliminating some variables from the equation, you might be able to narrow down your search a bit.

Comment: The problem ended up being I was attaching google charts to each row in a hidden popup dialog. Once I removed that, the memory usage went way down. By writing a test version, I found this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same thing.  I had a piece of code that polled every 10 seconds and retrieved a count of the current user's errors (data entry/auditing), a simple integer.  This was then used to replace the text inside a div (so the user knew when new errors were found in their work). If left overnight, the browser would end up using well over 1gb of memory!

The closest I came to solving the issue was reducing the polling to occur every 2 minutes instead and insist the user closed down at the end of the day.  A better solution still would have been to use Ajax Push Engine to push data to the page ONLY when an error was created.  This would have resulted in data being sent less frequently and thus less memory being used.

Comment: Sadly, we do have updates every 10-15 seconds, on all of the data. Also, since this is a "product", we can't require people to restart their browsers :) Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saving anything to an abject / array? I've had this happen before with a chrome plugin where an array just kept getting larger and larger. This sounds like it might be your problem, especially considering you're fetching 40k.

Comment: The request returns a large json object, but it overwrites the previous object in the same variable. That overwrites the same old block of content with the new.

Answer (score 1):

A snippet would be great it seems as if you are creating new variables each time and the old ones aren't going out of scope therefore not being garbage collected.

Also try and encapsulate more of your JS using constructors and instances of objects ect. When the JS is just a list of functions and all the variables have a global scope rather than being properties of an instance your JS can take up a lot memory.

Answer (score 1):

Why not draw the table and attach events only once and just replace the table data every 15 second?

Answer (score 1):

1) Jquery Ajax wrapper, called recurrently, leads to memory leaks and the community is aware of that (although the issue on the ajax wrapper is not by far as ugly as your case).

2) When it comes to optimization, you've done the first step(using lightweight json calls) and delete method, but that the problem is in the "event attaching" area and html method.

What I mean, is that:
1) you are probably reattaching the listener after each html() call
2) you re-draw the hole table on each ajax call.
This indeed leads to memory leaks.

You have to:
1)draw the table (with the first time content) on the server side
2)$(document).ready you attach listeners to the table's cells
3)call json service with ajax, parse response
4)refill table with the parsed array data

Tell us what you've achived meanwhile :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem just this week. It turned out I had a circular reference in my database. I had an inventory item `ABC123` flagged as being replaced by `XYZ321` and I also had `XYZ321` flagged as being replced by `ABC123`. Sometimes the circular reference is not in the PHP code.

Comment: When I say circular reference, I am talking about when an element refers to an object, which refers to the same element. Take a look at this writeup: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/